# Creación de objetos en un bucle

Tags: c#

Tengo que crear una lista de dispositivos electrónicos. Para ello, estoy haciendo un bucle for para crear 3 objetos, preguntar al usuario información por teclado y guardar los objetos en una lista. El problema es que cuando imprimo la lista, solo me guarda el último objeto introducido repetido 3 veces, y no se como hacer para que guarde uno por uno. Adjunto esa parte del código, muchas gracias. En el código se ve que lo introduzco en un archivo separado, pero eso no es útil.

```
           List<Dispositivo> dispositivosTienda = new List<Dispositivo>();
           string fileName = @"lista.txt";
           FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
           StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
           Telefono telefonos;

           int numeroOpcion;
           string numeroTexto;
           string nombreTelefono = "";
           string camarasTelefono;
           do
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el dispositivo que quiera introducir:\n1.-Teléfono móvil\n2.-Reloj inteligente\n3.-Memoria USB\n");
               numeroTexto = Console.ReadLine();
           } while (!int.TryParse(numeroTexto, out numeroOpcion));
           if(numeroOpcion == 1)
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
               {
                   telefonos = new Telefono();
                   Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el nombre del teléfono: ");
                   nombreTelefono = Console.ReadLine();
                   telefonos.SetNombreDispositivo(nombreTelefono);
                   Console.WriteLine("Introduzca el numero de camaras: ");
                   camarasTelefono = Console.ReadLine();
                   telefonos.SetNumeroCamaras(camarasTelefono);
                   string apple;
                   do
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Introduzca *si* si es de Apple y *no* por el contrario");
                       apple = Console.ReadLine();
                   } while (apple != "si" && apple != "no");
                   dispositivosTienda.Add(telefonos);

                   writer.WriteLine("Telefono:\nNombre: " + telefonos.GetNombreDispositivo(nombreTelefono) + ". Número de cámaras: " + telefonos.GetNumeroCamaras(camarasTelefono) + ". " + telefonos.marca(apple));
               }'''
```

Comment: No veo ninguna lista en tu código.

Comment: Perdone, ya está añadida. Dispositivo es una clase de la cual hereda teléfono